# How long does it take to get a tourist visa for Thailand in Chile?

Tags: visas, thailand, us-citizens, santiago-de-chile

I'm planning to request my [tourist visa for Thailand](http://www.thai-consulate.net/tourist-visa-for-thailand.html) from [the embassy here in Santiago, Chile](http://www.thai-consulate.net/royal-thai-embassy-in-chile.html).

However, my flight leaves mid next week, and I'm concerned that – even if I show up first thing tomorrow morning – my visa won't be ready by the time I need to leave.

What is the typical turnaround time on a Thai tourist visa at the embassy in Santiago, Chile?

Comment: Well, my question just got a lot less urgent — I visited the Thai embassy this morning, and they won't let me request a 60-day visa unless I am a resident of Chile.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for yourself? And did they happen to mention how long it takes for citizens - ie so that we might then have an answer for this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you commented, it's not necessarily possible there unless you are a Chilean resident.  However, assuming you are:

[SmileTravelVietnam has a page](http://www.smiletravelvietnam.com/thailand-embassy-in-santiago) on many embassies including the one in Santiago for Thailand (go figure).  They state there that the turn around time is 2 days to 1 week, presumably depending on whether you pay for express service, and how close to weekends/holidays you are, and busy travel times.